# Error building project in Heroku (invalid character in key name = ':')

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I can't build my project in Heroku, crashing on Pipfile. Heroku is linked with my Github repository, which is private for obvious reasons.
I tried other things too, but when I add 'worker: python bot.py' on Pipfile, it just doesn't build. There's no Pipfile.lock on my project. 
Logs:

```
    -----> Python app detected
 !     No 'Pipfile.lock' found! We recommend you commit this into your repository.
-----> Need to update SQLite3, clearing cache
-----> Installing python-3.6.9
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 438, in _parse_pipfile
           return contoml.loads(contents)
         File "/tmp/build_97bd7e093c4db06e0905838cbf26d2d1/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/contoml/__init__.py", line 14, in loads
           tokens = tuple(lexer(text, is_top_level=True))
         File "/tmp/build_97bd7e093c4db06e0905838cbf26d2d1/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/patched/prettytoml/lexer/__init__.py", line 108, in tokenize
           next_row, next_col, source[next_index:]))
       prettytoml.lexer.LexerError: failed to read the next token at (9, 4): : python bot.py
       worker: python bot.py


       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
           sys.exit(cli())
         File "/tmp/build_97bd7e093c4db06e0905838cbf26d2d1/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
           return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
         File "/tmp/build_97bd7e093c4db06e0905838cbf26d2d1/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
           rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         File "/tmp/build_97bd7e093c4db06e0905838cbf26d2d1/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
           return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
         File "/tmp/build_97bd7e093c4db06e0905838cbf26d2d1/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
           return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
         File "/tmp/build_97bd7e093c4db06e0905838cbf26d2d1/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
           return callback(*args, **kwargs)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 402, in install
           selective_upgrade=selective_upgrade,
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1785, in do_install
           pre = project.settings.get('allow_prereleases')
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 446, in settings
           return self.parsed_pipfile.get('pipenv', {})
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 392, in parsed_pipfile
           parsed = self._parse_pipfile(contents)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 441, in _parse_pipfile
           return toml.loads(contents)
         File "/tmp/build_97bd7e093c4db06e0905838cbf26d2d1/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/toml.py", line 176, in loads
           item + "'. Try quoting the key name.")
       toml.TomlDecodeError: Found invalid character in key name: ':'. Try quoting the key name.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

My Pipfile:

```
[packages] 
requests = "*"
python-telegram-bot = "*"

[scripts]
web: python bot.py
worker: python bot.py
```

It seems right for me, I don't know what to do...

Comment: `web = python bot.py` ???

Comment: [scripts]
web: python bot.py
worker: python bot.py

Comment: Shouldn't it be `=` instead of `:`?

Comment: I wrote it wrong in the question

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is with the **Pipfile** and **Pipfile.lock**
The Pipfile file is intended to specify packages requirements for your Python application or library, both to development and execution.
The file syntax will be:

```
[[source]] # Here goes your package sources (where you are downloading your packages from).
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages] # Here goes your package requirements for running the application and its versions (which packages you will use when running the application).
requests = "*"
flask = "*"
pandas = "*"

[dev-packages] # Here goes your package requirements for developing the application and its versions (which packages you will use when developing the application)
wheel = "*"

[requires] # Here goes your required Python version.
python_version = "3.6"
```

**Pipfile.lock**
The Pipfile.lock is intended to specify, based on the packages present in Pipfile, which specific version of those should be used, avoiding the risks of automatically upgrading packages that depend upon each other and breaking your project dependency tree.

use this command if Pipfile.lock is present.

```
$ pipenv lock
```

You can add `web: python bot.py` in Procfile